# Oracel Garbled characters were generated during import

Tags: oracle, character, imp

The client uses US7ASCII encoding to export DMP, any encoding used during import will result in annotated Chinese garbled characters. comment. view...

Comment: `Export done in US7ASCII character set and AL16UTF16 NCHAR character set`

Comment: `server uses ZHS16GBK character set (possible charset conversion)`

Comment: `import done in US7ASCII character set and AL16UTF16 NCHAR character set`

Comment: `import server uses ZHS16GBK character set (possible charset conversion)`

Comment: what do you mean by "server has ZHS16GBK" character set? Is it the DB or .....